# SSL: Certificate Verify Failed error when making request from langchain to HuggingFaceHub

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, langchain, huggingface

I run the following code in code on Windows using LangChain framework to make request from HuggingFaceHub:

```
from langchain.llms import HuggingFaceHub

os.environ["HUGGINGFACEHUB_API_TOKEN"] = "HuggingFaceHub_Key_here"

llm = HuggingFaceHub(repo_id = "google/flan-t5-large")
our_query = "What is the currency of Nigeria?"
completion = llm(our_query)
print(completion)
```

I received an SSL certificate verification error.
I checked HuggingFace website and found out that Chrome is displaying "Not secure" and "Certificate not valid" warning messages on huggingface.co website. I downloaded the huggingface.co certificate and added it to Windows Trusted Root Certification Authorities. Chrome didn't recognize the certificate. I added the HuggingFace certificate to Chrome through the Chrome Security/Manage Certificate, which Chrome allows but didn't add the certificate. Can someone help out to solve this problem?